# How do I know if my propensiy score estimation is correct?

Tags: propensity-scores

Are there any test statistics, visualization methods, or other methods to help me decide whether my propensity score estimates are correct?

Answer (score 3):

It's impossible to know if any estimate is correct, as AdamO mentions. You can assess whether your estimated propensity scores are adequate for reducing bias in an effect estimate by assessing covariate balance after matching or weighting on them. The best practices for assessing balance are described in the main vignette for the `cobalt` R package, which was designed to assess balance. There is a broad literature on best practices for balance assessment. I recommend reading [Ho, Imai, King, and Stuart (2007)](https://doi.org/10.1093/pan/mpl013) for information on how propensity scores should be assessed and [Austin (2009)](https://doi.org/10.1002/sim.3697) for modern good practices in balance assessment, in addition to the `cobalt` vignette.

Comment: Technically "balance" is only achieved when propensity matching, which introduces additional assumptions. Or maybe there's a more nuanced understanding of covariate balance when using the scores as a weighting variable?

Comment: Balance is well-defined and straightforward with weighting. It's not more nuanced; you just compute balance on the weighted covariate distributions. All balance measures have weighted versions. Weighting is more general than matching.

Answer (score 1):

Estimation is never correct, but it can be precise. Nothing along the lines of what you're asking for is specially developed for propensity scores; but when you view the problem as one of prediction, there's probably too many methods to count. Asking for test statistics is silly because you don't have a hypothesis. As far as plots, however, you can consider ROC curves, simple boxplots, or diagnostic plots related to the logistic regression model used to obtain the scores.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily check with standardized differences or similar statistics whether your propensity score, when used appropriately (eg with matching or inverse weighting), helps you in reducing the apparent bias/confounding due to measured confounders (eg https://atm.amegroups.com/article/view/22865/22385).

However, you may be fooled if a given confounder has been inappropriately labelled or measured (for instance think about the difficulty inherent in labelling sex/gender or race/ethnicity, eg https://ajph.aphapublications.org/doi/10.2105/AJPH.92.9.1471).

Most importantly, no propensity score can adjust for an unmeasured confounder (despite occasional claims for the opposite, eg https://www.jclinepi.com/article/S0895-4356(16)30334-1/fulltext).

In summary, as stated by AdamO and Noah, you may be precise (spuriously?) in your estimation, but accuracy is elusive, with randomized trials being the only really valid approach for hypothesis testing and effect size estimation of interventions.

Comment: Randomized trials aren't the only valid approach for estimating the causal effect of interventions, but they do require the fewest assumptions.

Comment: Whenever a randomized trial is feasible and ethical, I guess any other study design is less scientific and conclusive... but there is likely no randomized evidence supporting this (albeit well-grounded) hypothesis.

Comment: There is no doubt that RCTs are highly effective at what they do, but the questions they can answer are fairly limited. An RCT can answer a question about the small population from which the trial members were sampled (typically in a non-random way, making superpopulation inference fraught), whereas an observational study conducted using a nationally representative survey can tell you much more, at the cost of requiring additional assumptions, which are not always implausible. I only want to temper your strong claim that they are the only, or even best, way to make valid scientific claims.

Comment: I was curious about the article that you claim says propensity scores can adjust for unmeasured confounding... That isn't what the article says. It says you can use propensity score *calibration*, a specific method that uses a dataset with no measurement error to bring that information into the dataset at hand, which may have measurement error. This is a legitimate use of the method and doesn't imply researchers think propensity score matching removes unmeasured confounding (at least not in the papers examined in the study).